# Program is canceling after first function

Tags: go, process

i've got a problem with my go code. I'll try to build a script to automate my update and installing with syscall.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "syscall"
)

func update() {
    binary, lookErr := exec.LookPath("apt")
    if lookErr != nil {
        panic(lookErr)
    }

    args := []string{"apt", "update"}

    env := os.Environ()

    execErr := syscall.Exec(binary, args, env)
    if execErr != nil {
        panic(execErr)
    }

}

func upgrade() {
    binary, lookErr := exec.LookPath("apt")
    if lookErr != nil {
        panic(lookErr)
    }

    args := []string{"apt", "upgrade", "-y"}

    env := os.Environ()

    execErr := syscall.Exec(binary, args, env)
    if execErr != nil {
        panic(execErr)
    }
}

func main() {
    update()
    upgrade()
}
```

The code is only doing the first update() function. After that is canceling. No errors or anything. How could i manage to do it step by step?

Comment: "How could i manage to do it step by step?"  [Delve](https://github.com/derekparker/delve) is a good debugger for Go.  You can use it to step through your program.

Comment: What do you mean that the code "is canceling"? This example is quite small, it's probably faster to print some debug output in the code than to step through with a debugger if you want to know what's going on. Also, don't use the syscall package directly for executing commands, there is an `os/exec` package that will do it correctly for you.

Comment: Thats the whole code for now^^ just doing some go learning. Its only doing the apt update after that its not doing the apt upgrade -y. It should do the update and after that it should do apt upgrade -y. And yeah i know about the os/exec functions but there its not working at all. Its just giving me an error code 1.

Comment: @n1ghty: ignoring the error and trying to bypass it isn't going to help, it's just making things more complicated. Figure out why you're getting an error with `os/exec`, as that is very likely the whole problem here.

Comment: `package main

import (
 "log"
 "os/exec"
)

func update() {
 path, err := exec.LookPath("pacman")
 if err != nil {
  log.Fatal("pacman not found")
 }

 pathArgs := "-Syu"
 cmd := exec.Command(path, pathArgs)
 updateErr := cmd.Start()
 if err != nil {
  log.Fatal(updateErr)
 }
 log.Printf("Waiting for Update to finish")
 updateErr = cmd.Wait()
 log.Printf("Update failed: %v", updateErr)

}

func main() {
 update()
}
` exit status 1 is the problem. What does that mean?

Comment: @n1ghty: please don't put code in the comments, it's not really readable. If you want to know what failed for a command, look at the command's output.

Comment: You need to collect what the program writes to its standard error stream.

Answer (score 1):

To cite [the manual](https://manpages.debian.org/exec):

> The `exec()` family of functions *replaces the current process image* with a new process image.

(Emphasis mine).

To solve this, use the functions from `os/exec` and handle all the errors.